# Prevent enter key on EditText but still show the text as multi-line

Tags: android, android-edittext, multiline

How do I make an EditText on Android such that the user may not enter a multi-line text, but the display is still multi-line (i.e. there is word-wrap instead of the text going over to the right)?

It's similar to the built-in SMS application where we can't input newline but the text is displayed in multiple lines.

Comment: just add android:inputType="textPersonName" to the EditText it will stop it from pressing enter

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I would subclass the widget and override the key event handling in order to block the `Enter` key:

```
class MyTextView extends EditText
{
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) 
        {
            // Just ignore the [Enter] key
            return true;
        }
        // Handle all other keys in the default way
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Should this line: `return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);` be in onKeyDown or am I imagining? :P

Comment: We both are working for same community.
You're welcome jen.
:)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. (I upped the other answer too). Tip: you can avoid subclassing by just editText.setOnKeyListener(...) and return (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER).

Comment: enter key is still working in nexus with linear layout

Comment: @Dr. aNdRO Which version of Android?

Comment: This didn't worked in case of Google keyboard but worked well for Android default keyboard. When I switch keyboards, different behaviour occurred.

Comment: Almost no keyboards actually send key events.  Those are meant for hardware keys.  They almost all use commitText, which will not call this function.

Answer (score 49):

This is a method, where you don't have to override the EditText class. You just catch and replace the newlines with empty strings.

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

}

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    /*
     * The loop is in reverse for a purpose,
     * each replace or delete call on the Editable will cause
     * the afterTextChanged method to be called again.
     * Hence the return statement after the first removal.
     * http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#afterTextChanged(android.text.Editable)
     */
    for(int i = s.length()-1; i >= 0; i--){
        if(s.charAt(i) == '\n'){
            s.delete(i, i + 1);
            return;
        }
    }
}
});
```

Credit to [Rolf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1052697/rolf-%e3%83%84) for improvement on an earlier answer.

Comment: +1 This was more useful in my case than the accepted answer, for the simple reason, that I can use it as a default implementation of TextWatcher, which can be expanded by subclasses (Which would then simply call super.afterTextChanged(...) to retain that check for line breaks. Works !

Comment: For-loop condition should be `i > 0` rather than `i >= 0`. When `i == 0`, `s.subSequence(i-1, i)` gets an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: I think this throws an IndexOutOfBoundsException for text with new line that is copy and pasted in with multiple new line characters.

Comment: @TalkLittle I posted another answer with the correct code, only changing the for loop condition doesn't fix the IndexOufOfBoundsException. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36485266/1052697

Answer (score 23):

---

Property in XML

```
android:lines="5"
android:inputType="textPersonName"
```

Comment: Thanks, the simplest! Although I noticed it prevented my click listener on the ET from working... so use `editText.setSingleLine(false);` instead if so.

Comment: This is totally dependent on the keyboard used. Many will still show an enter key

Answer (score 14):

This one works for me:

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="textShortMessage|textMultiLine"
    android:minLines="3"
    ... />
```

It shows a smiley instead of the Enter key.

Comment: From experience this does not work on every keyboard. A HTC phone we had around still displayed the enter key.

Comment: This is totally dependent on the keyboard used.  Many will still show an enter key

Comment: If you long press on the smiley button in a Nexus 6, then you are still able to add a line break. Thus this is no general solution then.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a more correct answer that does not display the enter key on the IME keyboard:

```
// IMPORTANT, do this before any of the code following it
myEditText.setSingleLine(true);

// IMPORTANT, to allow wrapping
myEditText.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
// IMPORTANT, or else your edit text would wrap but not expand to multiple lines
myEditText.setMaxLines(6);
```

Also, you may replace `setSingleLine(true)` with either, an explicit `android:inputType` on the XML layout file, or `setInputType(InputType.*)` on code – in which, the input type used, is anything that you know restricts the input to single lines only (i.e., anything that calls `setSingleLine(true)` implicitly already).

---

**Explanation:**

What `setSingleLine(true)` does is calling `setHorizontallyScrolling(true)` and `setLines(1)` implicitly, alongside with altering some IME keyboard settings to disable the enter key.

In turn, the call to `setLines(1)` is like calling `setMinLines(1)` and `setMaxLines(1)` in one call.

Some input types (i.e., the constants from `InputType.TYPE_*`) calls `setSingleLine(true)` implicitly, or at least achieves the same effect.

**Conclusion:**

So to achieve what the OP wants, we simply counter those implicit settings by reverting those implicit calls.

Answer (score 8):

The answer provided by @Andreas Rudolph contains a critical bug and shouldn't be used. The code causes an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when you past text inside the `EditText` which contains multiple new-line characters. This is caused by the type of loop which is used, the `Editable` object  will call the `afterTextChanged` method as soon as its contents change (replace, delete, insert).

**Correct code:**

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        /*
         * The loop is in reverse for a purpose,
         * each replace or delete call on the Editable will cause
         * the afterTextChanged method to be called again.
         * Hence the return statement after the first removal.
         * http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#afterTextChanged(android.text.Editable)
         */
        for(int i = s.length()-1; i >= 0; i--){
            if(s.charAt(i) == '\n'){
                s.delete(i, i + 1);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You should have edited the answer, instead of making a new one.

Comment: @RobertMartin I was wondering this myself and asked for help on the Meta website, they suggested that I should post a new answer. Because the changes I would have made conflicted with the author's original intends.

Comment: Nice! However, if you start by hitting the Enter key you'll still have a new line at the beginning (so `i>=0` should work) ^^

Comment: Nice Solution. For someone looking for code in Kotlin :                                                  for (i in s.length - 1 downTo 0) {
 if(s[i] == '\n') {
  s.delete(i, i + 1)
  return
 }
}

Comment: I took this answer and replaced my old one with it.

Comment: @AndreasRudolph maybe add a small credit in your answer as well?

Comment: Done @Rolfツ! Thanks for the improvement

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
    {
        //Nothing
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: No. This constrains the edit to a single line. The OP wants multiple lines; he just doesn't want the user to be able to enter line breaks.

Comment: Almost no keyboards actually send key events. Those are meant for hardware keys. They almost all use commitText, which will not call this function.

Answer (score 5):

I'm testing this and it seems to work:

```
EditText editText = new EditText(context);
editText.setSingleLine(false);
editText.setInputType(android.text.InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | android.text.InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_SUBJECT);
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. Setting anything in the XML was disabling my ET click listeners... so doing it this way did not! The return key on the keyboard changes into a "Done" button. (I only needed the `editText.setSingleLine(false);`).

Comment: This is totally dependent on the keyboard used. Many will still show an enter key

Answer (score 3):

You can set it from the xml like this:

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
android:inputType="text"
android:maxLines="10"
```

don't forget `android:inputType="text"`, if you don't set it, it doesn't work. I don't know why though.
Also don't forget to change `maxLines` to your preferred value.

Comment: This is totally dependent on the keyboard used. Many will still show an enter key

Answer (score 3):

Simply add

```
        android:singleLine="true"
```

to your EditText

Comment: This is deprecated!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution....

```
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/editText"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:maxLength="150"                                 
   android:textSize="15dp"
   android:imeOptions="actionDone"
   android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"/>
```

**Usage in java class**

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
            {
                // Just ignore the [Enter] key
                return true;
            }
            // Handle all other keys in the default way
            return (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for your answer. Could you format it properly, please, e.g. by seperating text and code part as  `Here is the solution...`? Some more background information is also helpful. Thanks.

Comment: You already return `true` when `keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER`. So, next will return `false`.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer worked so well until I copied text with line-breaks into into the EditText. So I added onTextContextMenuItem to monitor the paste action.

```
@Override
public boolean onTextContextMenuItem(int id) {
    boolean ret = super.onTextContextMenuItem(id);
    switch (id) {
        case android.R.id.paste:
            onTextPaste();
            break;
    }
    return ret;
}

public void onTextPaste() {
    if (getText() == null)
        return;
    String text = getText().toString();
    text = text.replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator"), " ");
    text = text.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
    setText(text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the action button from code

```
editText.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT)
```

Xml

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

Answer (score 0):

For a [URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) you could use:

```
android:inputType="textUri"
android:lines="1"
android:maxLength="128"
```

Otherwise `android:inputType="textPersonName"` as mentioned above works for other EditText such user name, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditText 
  android:id="@+id/Msg"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"              
  android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
  android:lines="5"
  android:selectAllOnFocus="true"               
  android:hint="Skriv meddelande...\n(max 100tkn)"/>


EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Msg);
String strTmp = et.getText().toString();
strTmp = strTmp.replaceAll("\\n"," ");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    EditText textView = new EditText(activity);
    ...
    textView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER == keyEvent.getKeyCode()) {
                return false;
            }
            ....... 

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I will give another option so you don't have to subclass EditText. Create an `InputFilter` that filters out linebreaks. Then use `EditText.addInputFilter`.

Source code for such an input filter is here: https://gist.github.com/CapnSpellcheck/7c72830e43927380daf5205100c93977

You can pass 0 in the constructor, and it won't allow any newlines. Also, you can combine this with one of the other tweaks such as `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`, as this will help improve the experience on some devices.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Set the EditText to multiline
 * Starting with one line and expanding to maxLines = line
 * the next action will be force to IME_ACTION_NEXT
 */
fun TextInputEditText.setMultilineTextNextAction(lines: Int) {
    imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT
    setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT)
    maxLines=lines
}
```

ALso, control the length of input text with android:maxLength, as:

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/textEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="@style/WmTextBody"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:maxLength="100"
            />
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding this property to the `EditText` XML works for me:

```
android:lines="1"
```

It lets the users input newline characters but the `EditText` itself does not increase in height.