# I need to configure a multiline edit text but never leave a newline ENTER

Tags: android, android-edittext

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent enter key on EditText but still show the text as multi-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070805/prevent-enter-key-on-edittext-but-still-show-the-text-as-multi-line)

I need to configure a multiline edit text but never leave a newline ENTER, only characters.

```
EditText editText = new EditText(context);
editText.setSingleline(false);
editText.setInputType( ???? );
```

Thanks

Comment: Thansk for your reply @Eric.
I found also this way but I do not like to mail keyboard appears. I leave it in case anyone is useful. Greetings.

**`editText.setInputType(android.text.InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | android.text.InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS)`**

Comment: TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_SUBJECT (no EMAIL_ADDRESS)